# Finding tie points between a georeferenced and a non geo referenced image

Tags: georeferencing, software-recommendations, open-source-gis, orthorectification

Is there an open source program for finding tie points between a non-georeferenced image and a georeferenced image? I am looking for something I  can run at the command line in linux to incorporate into a processing chain, that outputs the tie points in image coordinates in the un-referenced image,  as well as in geographic coordinates.

Comment: Something like Hugin for georeferencing. Great Idea !

Answer (score 2):

I came across AROSICS, or An Automated and Robust Open-Source Image Co-Registration Software for Multi-Sensor Satellite Data by Daniel Scheffler, which is a python library and command line tools for warping one (roughly) georeferenced image to a reference image:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arosics/0.8.0

The python library gives you access to the tie points. It's a good idea to follow the install instructions exactly, and set up a dedicated anaconda environment - the python kernel would crash when I tried to install and run it in my default conda installation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [AROP](https://www.ars.usda.gov/research/software/download/?softwareid=364) from USDA.

This is not open source, but free and working in command lines on Linux, so it has the features that you are looking for.

Reference

Gao., F., Masek, J. G., Wolfe, R. F., An automated registration and orthorectification package for Landsat and Landsat-like data processing, Journal of Applied Remote Sensing, Vol.3, 033515, doi: 10.1117/1.3104620, 2009. (copyright SPIE JARS)